# How to create iterative boost threads?

Tags: multithreading, loops, boost, iteration

I am working with Boost threads library in C++ and I want to create different threads to process some buckets of data. Firstly, I load the data into smaller buckets (100 elements each) and assign each bucket to a thread. The available threads are four, so I avoid to create new threads until there is free a new thread. A pseudocode follows:

```
while(pool1->has_next()){

    int tmp = pool->get_next();
    pool2->pushback(tmp);

    if(pool2->size()%100==0){

        while(working_threads>=4){
            wait();
        }
        new thread (proc(pool2));
    }
    pool2->clear();
}
```

How can this be done with Boost threads?

Comment: I don't understand very well your pseudo code: why do you clear `pool2` _inconditionally_ at the end of the loop? what does `proc` do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a thread pool or thread group, which I have an example of on github:

git@github.com:cdesjardins/JobBatcher.git

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that incoming data are large to fit in the pool (memory), so I must set an appropriate pool size and if the pool is full to wait until there is empty space. is that possible ?